# Target V4.7.2 and netcoreapp3.1 in same project. Value does not fall witnin the expected range

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, csproj, netcoreapp3.1

I want my Framework 4.7.2 code to use a library that targets netcoreapp3.1
Nuget indicates that the library is referenced, yet I do not see it in the list of references.

I tried editing the project to change the TargetFrameworkVersion from

```xml
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

to

```xml
<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2;netcoreapp3.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

But saving this change causes a message

[image: from Visual Studio]

And I cannot re-load the project

I tried chainging to

```xml
<TargetFrameworkVersion>netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworkVersion>
```

The build error becomes

```
Error       The expression "[Microsoft.Build.Utilities.ToolLocationHelper]::
GetPathToStandardLibraries(.NETFramework, netcoreapp3.1;net472, '', '', '', '')" 
cannot be evaluated. Input string was not in a correct format.
```

I asked a related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62256011/nu1201project-mopcore-is-not-compatible-with-net472-when-a-netcore-dll-is-refe) to try and troubleshoot this.

Comment: http://hermit.no/moving-to-sdk-style-projects-and-package-references-in-visual-studio-part-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your looking for `<TargetFrameworks>`

so in this case:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;net472</TargetFrameworks>
```

Please note you need a SDK-style csproj. I assume this in the case for you. If not, check [How to upgrade csproj files with VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42659684/how-to-upgrade-csproj-files-with-vs2017)

See also [the article about `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform?view=vs-2019):

> This article shows the old way to specify a target framework. SDK-style projects enable different TargetFrameworks like netstandard. For more info, see Target frameworks.